# Woocommerce order data not displaying, such as shipping address

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have some problems on my woocommerce website. As you see on screenshot, the order data part is missing.

I disabled plugins which can make this happen. But nothing changes at all.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

- Wordpress theme: Megashop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.panel#order_data {
display:block;
}
```

Adding this to admin_css.css file solved the problem.